# Real time audio visualization program to use with any sound source

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, mixxx

I'm looking for a **standalone application** to show some **nice-looking video special effects**, computed in **real-time from the sound output** (such as what [*Winamp* was doing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-34Qqd0mAfo) with plugins).

*The context*: I'm using [Mixxx](https://www.mixxx.org/) to handle an audio playlist, and with a projected external display I'd like to show some visual effects based on the sound output I'm generating. (All this with Pulse-audio).

Does this kind of application exists? What is the name to search for? I've tried many searches on the web, w/o finding the correct type of program.

Comment: How about this: https://superuser.com/questions/291600/linux-realtime-audio-visualizer/1115900

Comment: Indeed, ProjectM fits the bill perfectly. It is by far the most complete and mature project I've seen that correspond to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ProjectM

ProjectM is an open source music visualizer based on the Milkdrop plugin for Windows/Winamp. It now has a Qt GUI that can visualize your audio output through either JACK or PulseAudio, in addition to a libvisual component. This wiki currently focuses on the PulseAudio standalone GUI.

LK